# Matlab editor not using emacs shortcuts

Tags: matlab, editor, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there some way I can make the matlab integrated editor not use emacs shortcut, but use more normal shortcuts such that I can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> and not be completely confused by the editor doing weird stuff?

I'm using matlab on linux btw.

Comment: Meh! Emacs keystrokes *are* the normal ones...

Comment: @dmckee: It might be the default, but for most users they are just confusing. CTRL-v are so hardcoded in my behavior that I will always do that without thinking when I intent to paste a line before using another shortcut. If CTRL-v did nothing there would be no problem, but it seems that it goes to the last line in the script, which results in me being completely confused and loose my line of thought.

The same goes for CTRL-s, which I push without thinking at least 10 times a minute when editing a document or script.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

File -> Preference -> Keyboard -> Choose windows

Comment: Thank you very much. I was just about to go crazy.

Answer (score 9):

Since Matlab 2012, with ribbon UI:

Home Tab -> Environment Section -> Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Active settings: -> Windows Default Set

Answer (score 6):

File -> Preference -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Active settings: -> Windows Default Set