# Tab key working strangely in Matlab editor?

Tags: matlab, editor

My <kbd>Tab</kbd> key has suddenly started acting strange in Matlab (R2011b) editor. It's working **backwards**!

Pressing it doesn't add tab spaces and whenever I press it after a couple of spaces, the cursor comes back to the first place.

I've checked the Matlab keyboard preferences and everything seems fine. Tab action is assigned to the Tab key. Also, turning the Tab Completion on/off or changing the Tab size didn't have any effect on it.

Anybody has any idea how to fix this?

**Note:** it's working fine in other applications and also in the console window.

Comment: why is this "off-topic"? It's a question regarding the use of [matlab]+[editor]? This seems like a valid question.

Comment: ^ Yes. Why is this voted off-topic, but a question like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934766/matlab-editor-not-using-emacs-shortcuts?rq=1) is not?

Comment: Rather, why is it closed instead of being migrated to [SU]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are experiencing "smart indenting" behavior.

Check the "smart indenting" option in your preferences. Make sure it is turned off. I think it is located in File→Preferences→Editor/Debugger→Language, and in
File→Preferences→Editor/Debugger→Tab, under "Emacs-style Tab key smart indenting".

For more info see [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/about-editor-debugger-preferences.html#bs237bq-7).

Comment: I like smart indenting. You can go to the editor, press ctrl-a, then tab, and everything is appropriately indented (if you don't mind the matlab decisions on what should and shouldn't be indented, that is).

Comment: @Shai, Thank you so much! It was the "Emacs-style smart indenting" that was causing the problem. Turning it off solved it.

Comment: @HughNolan, I use Ctrl+A then Ctrl+I for what smart indenting the whole code.